# Org-mode: how to prevent line from being included in section?

Tags: org-mode

I have an org-file, which I've wrapped in a `div` for html export. This div is necessary because it is targeted by some custom css.

```
#+html: <div id="wrapper-div">

* Section One
* Section Two
* Etc.

#+html: </div>
```

The problem is that the `</div>` always gets folded into the last section. This wouldn't be a huge deal, but it's annoying when I add a new section to the end because this misplaces the `</div>` tag (being folded into the previous section).

Can I somehow mark the line, `#+html: </div>`, as non-collapsible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add something to the top-level after introducing a heading.

However, there might be another solution for you by advising the export functions. I prepared two examples on how to achieve what you want, since I do not know whether you want to cover the content including the table of content or not. The first (`org-html-template-around`) covers also the table of content, the second (`org-html-inner-template-around`) only the content.

```el
(defun org-html-template-around (org-fun &rest args)
  (let ((content (car args))
        (info (cadr args)))
    (apply org-fun (list (concat "<div id=\"wrapper-div\">"
                             content
                             "</div>")
                         info))))
(advice-add 'org-html-template :around #'org-html-template-around)

(defun org-html-inner-template-around (org-fun &rest args)
  (let ((content (car args))
        (info (cadr args)))
    (apply org-fun (list (concat "<div id=\"inner-wrapper-div\">"
                             content
                             "</div>")
                         info))))
(advice-add 'org-html-inner-template :around #'org-html-inner-template-around)
```

You may want to set a customization variable, probably buffer local, to enable and disable your addition on a per file basis.

```el
(defvar-local org-html-inner-template-around-id nil
  "If non nil: wrap html export in div with id given by this var.")
(defun org-html-inner-template-around (org-fun &rest args)
  (let ((content (car args))
        (info (cadr args)))
    (when org-html-inner-template-around-id
      (setq content (concat (format "<div id=\"%s\">" org-html-inner-template-around-id)
                             content
                             "</div>")))
    (apply org-fun (list content info))))
(advice-add 'org-html-inner-template :around #'org-html-inner-template-around-id)
```

Then you can set the variable in your org file, e.g. with the following first line:

```el
# -*- org-html-inner-template-around-id: findme-as-div; -*-
```

See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables) for more information on specifying file variables.

If you use `ox-twbs` then advice `org-twbs-template` or `org-twbs-inner-template` respectively.

Comment: This is more complicated than I had hoped, but I appreciate the generality of your solution and your time in writing it out. Stupid question: where would the first two code blocks be defined? In the init file?

Comment: Yes, you can put the function definitions in your `init.el`. Be sure to have `(require 'ox-html)` before you try to `advice-add`.